# D3 - add text when clicking

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to append and then remove a little bit of text when the user clicks a little plotted node (d3). I have the click function working, however I am struggling trying to add a bit of text. Here is what I have -

```
.on("click",function(d){
          d3.select(this)
           .append("text")
    .attr("dx", function(d){return -20})
    .text(function(d){return d.depth})
            .transition()
            .duration(600)
            .attr("r",function(d){
                  return d.depth;
              })
            .attr("opacity", 0.1)
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .attr("r",function(d){
                  return d.magnitude/1.5;
              })
            .attr("opacity", 0.8)
            //remove text here
        })
```

This works as intended if I dont have the append part for the text like this -

```
  .on("click",function(d){
          d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(600)
            .attr("r",function(d){
                  return d.depth;
              })
            .attr("opacity", 0.1)
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .attr("r",function(d){
                  return d.magnitude/1.5;
              })
            .attr("opacity", 0.8)
        })
```

So I am just trying to have the text pop up and then remove once the animations are done.

Comment: Remember that you can't append `text` elements to any element -- it would have to be a `g` element.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff it is chained off a g - i realized it is showing up on the dom, i just cant see it for whatever reason, possibly needs styling?

Comment: Hard to tell. `text` elements don't have `r` attributes though. Does it work without the transitions?

Comment: I think you could try and add the .text after the attributes of the d3.select(this) elements, which I guess is a circle. I believe that could be a possible solution